# Horizontal bar in matrix to indicate row vector

Tags: matrices

To indicate that a vector represents a column of a matrix, we can write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    \vert & \vert \\
    \vec{u} & \vec{v} \\
    \vert & \vert
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

To achieve [image: Vertical indicator]

How can I do the same to indicate a vector represents a row (looks like [image: Horizontal Indicator])?

Detexify doesn't return anything that looks like what I want (it thinks I'm drawing an underscore).

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please always provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and `\end{document}` on the end. see, if `[-\; \vec{v}\; - ]` gives what you looking for (so far i didn't see such notations for vectors ...)

Comment: Even without `\vert` it makes complete sense that a vertical (or horizontal) vector would span multiple columns.

Comment: I added images for reference. @Zarko, what you suggested works for me, but do you know if there's a command similar to \vert but generates a horizontal line so I don't have to add the extra semicolons? As an analogy, I'm looking for a command that is to \vert like what \hdots is to \vdots.

Comment: no, i don't know. but probably it can be composed from some elements or drawn, for example with use of the package `nicematrix`. however, your notation is strange. for similar purposes are usually use `\dots`, `\vdots`, `\ddots` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rotate a `\vert`, so you get the same thickness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\brows}[1]{%
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{@{\protect\rotvert\;}c@{\;\protect\rotvert}}
  #1
  \end{array}
  \end{bmatrix}
}
\newcommand{\rotvert}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\vert$}}
\newcommand{\rowsvdots}{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\vdots}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    \vert & \vert \\
    \vec{u} & \vec{v} \\
    \vert & \vert
\end{bmatrix}
+
\brows{a_1^T \\ a_2^T \\ \rowsvdots \\ a_n^T}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]